# Unable to access databricks cluster with databricks-connect "V2" V.13.2

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

When trying to execute local spark code with databricks-connect 13.2.0, it does not work.

I have the following issue:

Error:

- details = `"INVALID_STATE: cluster xxxxx is not Shared or Single User Cluster. (requestId=05bc3105-4828-46d4-a381-7580f3b55416)"`
- debug_error_string = `"UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {grpc_message:"INVALID_STATE: cluster 0711-122239-bb999j6u is not Shared or Single User Cluster. (requestId=05bc3105-4828-46d4-a381-7580f3b55416)", grpc_status:9, created_time:"2023-07-11T15:26:08.9729+02:00"}"`

The cluster is Shared and I tried several cluster configurations but it doest not work !
The cluster runtime version is 13.2.

Also, I use:

- Python 3.10
- openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
- Azure Databricks

Any one had a similar issue with new databricks connect ?

Thanks for help!

I tried the following code:

```
from databricks.connect import DatabricksSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

from delta.tables import DeltaTable
from datetime import date


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = DatabricksSession.builder.getOrCreate()

    # Create a Spark DataFrame consisting of high and low temperatures
    # by airport code and date.
    schema = StructType([
        StructField('AirportCode', StringType(), False),
        StructField('Date', DateType(), False),
        StructField('TempHighF', IntegerType(), False),
        StructField('TempLowF', IntegerType(), False)
    ])

    data = [
        [ 'BLI', date(2021, 4, 3), 52, 43],
        [ 'BLI', date(2021, 4, 2), 50, 38],
        [ 'BLI', date(2021, 4, 1), 52, 41],
        [ 'PDX', date(2021, 4, 3), 64, 45],
        [ 'PDX', date(2021, 4, 2), 61, 41],
        [ 'PDX', date(2021, 4, 1), 66, 39],
        [ 'SEA', date(2021, 4, 3), 57, 43],
        [ 'SEA', date(2021, 4, 2), 54, 39],
        [ 'SEA', date(2021, 4, 1), 56, 41]
    ]

    temps = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

    print(temps)
```

And I expect to display the dataframe in may local terminal with remote spark  execution

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this? Currently experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 6):

Databricks Connect V2 requires cluster supporting Unity Catalog - it explicitly stated in the [requirements](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#requirements).  And looks like you're using Data Access mode "No Isolation Shared" or you don't have Unity Catalog at all.  If you have Unity Catalog, make sure that you have selected `Single User` or `Shared` in  "Access mode" dropdown.

[image]

Comment: So no way using databricks-connect if the cluster (13.3 LTE) is not yet supporting Unity Catalog?

Comment: DBConnect V2 is supporting 13.3, but it should be Unity Catalog-enabled cluster (single user or shared), not "Shared No Isolation"

Comment: I understand.  But in my company Unity Support is not yet enabled.  Still I want to use 13.3 LTS and get above error.  Is there a workaround until we have Unity?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, it’s not possible to use it without Unity Catalog… No workaround

Comment: To share, my cluster (runtime 13.3) uses hive metastore without Unity catalog. Databricks-connect doesn't work with `Shared` mode (it complains about permission issue) but it works with `Single User`

Comment: @AlexOtt any information as to why this only works with a unity catalog cluster? This was no requirement before and to me there is no obvious technical requirement for this. This makes using the VSCode extension + databricks connect much more annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you create a cluster in the summary you see the `Unity Catalog` tag:
[image]

And as answered by Alex Ott, either select `Single User` or `Shared` in the Dropdown Access Mode.